# How to write binary values into a file in Bash instead of ASCII values

Tags: linux, bash, devices, echo, hex

I am dealing with an embedded system which has some memory that is accessible by a file descriptor (I have no idea what am I saying, so please correct me if I am wrong).

This memory is 32 kB and I want to fill it with 0x00 to 0xFFFFFFFF. I know this for text files:

```
exec {fh} >> ./eeprom;
for i in {0..32767}; do echo $i >& $fh; done; $fh>&-;
```

This will write ASCII characters 0 to 977.

And if I do a `hexdump eeprop | head` I get:

```
0000000 0a30 0a31 0a32 0a33 0a34 0a35 0a36 0a37
0000010 0a38 0a39 3031 310a 0a31 3231 310a 0a33
0000020 3431 310a 0a35 3631 310a 0a37 3831 310a
0000030 0a39 3032 320a 0a31 3232 320a 0a33 3432
0000040 320a 0a35 3632 320a 0a37 3832 320a 0a39
0000050 3033 330a 0a31 3233 330a 0a33 3433 330a
0000060 0a35 3633 330a 0a37 3833 330a 0a39 3034
0000070 340a 0a31 3234 340a 0a33 3434 340a 0a35
0000080 3634 340a 0a37 3834 340a 0a39 3035 350a
0000090 0a31 3235 350a 0a33 3435 350a 0a35 3635
```

How can I fill each address with its `uint32`, not the ASCII representation?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/794902/2954288, `xxd`.

Comment: Another cross-site dup: [How to create binary file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521240/how-to-create-binary-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
perl -e 'print pack "L*", 0..0x7fff' > file
```

Would write them in the local system's endianness.

Use:

```
perl -e 'print pack "L>*", 0..0x7fff'
perl -e 'print pack "L<*", 0..0x7fff'
```

To force big-endian or little-endian respectively regardless of the native endianness of the local system.

See `perldoc -f pack` for details.

With bash builtins specifically, you can write arbitrary *byte* values with:

```
printf '\123' # 123 in octal
printf '\xff' # ff in hexadecimal
```

So you could do it by writing each byte of the uint32 numbers by hand with something like:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 32767; i++)); do
  printf -v format '\\x%x' \
    "$((         i & 0xff ))" \
    "$(( (i >>  8) & 0xff ))" \
    "$(( (i >> 16) & 0xff ))" \
    "$(( (i >> 24) & 0xff ))"
  printf "$format"
done
```

(here in little-endian).

In any case, note that 32767 is 0x7fff, not *0xFFFFFFFF*. uint32 numbers 0 to 32767 take up 128KiB, not 32kb. 0 to 0xFFFFFFFF would take up 16GiB.

To write those 16GiB in `perl`, you'd need to change the code to:

```
perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffffff'
```

As otherwise it would try (and likely fail) to allocate those 16GiB in memory. On my system, I find `perl` writes the output at around 30MiB/s, while `bash` writes it at around 250KiB/s (so would take hours to complete).

To write 32kb (32000 bits, 4000 bytes, 1000 uint32 numbers) worth of uint32 numbers, you'd use the 0..999 range. 0..8191 for 32KiB. Or you could write 0..16383 as uint16 numbers by replacing `L` (unsigned long) with `S` (unsigned short).

Comment: Thanks for the good points. Yeah I was wrong about the 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: On a side note, can you please say how to set the content of the file back to all 0s?

Comment: @DEKKER, `head -c 131072 < /dev/zero 1<> file` overwrites the first 128KiB of `file` with 0s. See also `fallocate -p` to punch holes into a file.

Comment: Very interesting that Perl manages to be so much faster than a shell!!!

Comment: @paulgarrett, not that surprising, a shell is designed to run commands (such as the perl interpreter), perl is a generic programming language.

Answer (score 4):

Use C. This will be slightly faster than the Perl.

```
#include <unistd.h>
// in bytes, and MUST be sizeof(int) * somevalue
#define BSZ 4096

int main(void) {
    // TWEAK how far to go up to (set below 0xFFFFFFFF to actually
    // be testable on the 2009 macbook with a spinny metal drive and
    // no main CPU fan. the other laptop is even older and slower)
    // NOTE that max MUST fit exactly into a full buf
    unsigned long max = 0xFFFFFF;

    int buf[BSZ];
    unsigned long buf_size = BSZ;
    unsigned long buf_nint = BSZ / sizeof(int);
    unsigned long total    = 0;

    while (total < max) {
        unsigned long i = 0;
        for (; i < buf_nint; i++) {
            // TWEAK on little-endian you can htonl(3) this
            // to get one of the other byte orders, if you
            // need that. other byte orders on other systems
            // will be more complicated
            buf[i] = (int) (total + i);
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, buf_size);
        total += i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can still use the Perl to confirm that the C is not too terrible:

```
% perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffff' > p.out
% cc -O2 -std=c99 incrnumberfill.c -o incrnumberfill
% ./incrnumberfill > c.out
% cmp {p,c}.out
% echo $?
0
% repeat 3; time perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffff' > /dev/null
perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffff' > /dev/null  4.11s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 4.151 total
perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffff' > /dev/null  4.43s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 4.471 total
perl -e 'print pack "L", $_ for 0..0xffffff' > /dev/null  4.38s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 4.420 total
% repeat 3; time ./incrnumberfill > /dev/null
./incrnumberfill > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.01s system 88% cpu 0.035 total
./incrnumberfill > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.01s system 86% cpu 0.035 total
./incrnumberfill > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.01s system 88% cpu 0.034 total
```

Comment: In my experience, going from shell to perl (or python or ...) is often worth while even for one-off tasks, but going from there to C takes so much longer than the time you'll save because C is faster.

Comment: Except I like writing things in C, and have re-written a goodly portion of my scripts into it. (Possibly if I ever get a system from this or the previous decade I've heard good things about rust, but not on a 2009 macbook.)